# Build a cron expression to run in defined minutes and run only once (non repeatable)

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to build a corn expression for 2 of my use-cases using quartz scheduler,

1. which should in defined minutes, ex) If I schedule the job at 10:00 then it should trigger/execute the job at 10:20 only once.

I have created the expression `20 * * * *` [here](https://crontab.guru/#20_*_*_*_*) But it seems like invalid.

I can able to create cron expression to run every 20 mins using following expression `*/20 * * * *` but we cannot able to create an expression to run only in 20mins instead of every 20mins? I can create the job non-repeatable using quartz but that's the only way to achieve it?

2. How to build a corn expression to run immediately and only once not repeatable? This is also can able be achievable using a quartz scheduler by immediately triggering the job but we cannot able to achieve it via expression?

Any help should be really appreciable.

Comment: Maybe what you want is `at(1)`.

Comment: Hi @Roadowl thank you ....but what I want is cron expression 

Comment: It shouldn't really be a problem. Specify the time you want, the script you want and then let the script self destruct as it were ;-)  Seriously, let the script check for a flag file like e.g. `~/.script-was-run` and exit immediately if that exists.

Comment: To be clear, the script itself creates the flag file, in the final stage of its first succesful run.

Comment: But here I’m using quartz scheduler not script ....quartz execute the job based on cron expression....seems like we can write expression for all the cases like I mentioned in the question so we should use scheduler capabilities like don’t retry after the job is completed etc etc

Comment: Are you having cron execute a scheduler?

Comment: How about a wrapper script around the quartz-scheduler that handles the flag file?

Comment: Yes based on the cron expression scheduler will trigger the job. I hope this is how quartz work but I may be wrong because I’m new to quartz.